# 301 Redirect of folder to parent folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect /portfolio/year/ to /portfolio/.

The issue with the 301 I have written currently (redirect 301 /portfolio/year http://example.com/portfolio/) is that it redirects when someone attempts to access /portfolio/year/2000 or any of the other pages inside /year/.

Is there a way I can do this redirect? I need to keep bots and people from accessing the blank /portfolio/year/ page without breaking the rest of the internal pages.

Comment: I ended up doing a PHP redirect in the header - checking the URL and redirecting if on that specific page.

Comment: You should still accept the answer below if it accurately answers your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use PHP for this. Just replace your old RewriteRule with this one: `RewriteRule ^portfolio/year/?$ portfolio [R=301]` The `$` at the end of the url makes sure that there are no more characters after `portfolio/year/` or `portfolio/year`

Comment: I would have used `RewriteRule ^portfolio/year/$ portfolio [L,R=301]`